# Page transition In Applets With Button

Tags: java, applet, jbutton, transition, japplet

i had designed two applets in eclipse and when I click a button I want to show second applet's design how can I do it with mouseClicked method?

this is my first code.

```
JButton btnReserveASeat = new JButton("RESERVE A SEAT NOW!");
        btnReserveASeat.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Policies ();
        }
    });
```

this is my second code that i want to give link in button.

```
public class Policies extends JApplet {

    /**
     * Create the applet.
     */
    public Policies() {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
                ColumnSpec.decode("450px"),},
            new RowSpec[] {
                RowSpec.decode("29px"),
                FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
```

Goes like this.

Comment: Why code an applet(s)?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 2):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    new Policies ();
}
```

Should be something like:

```
URL url = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "policies.html");
// ..
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ThisApplet.getAppletContext().showDocument(url);
}
```